# Select while ignore duplicate by 2 rows with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have this table `scan`:

```
id   ip           port  text
-----------------------------
1    192.168.0.1    2   text1
2    192.168.0.1    2   text2
3    192.168.0.1    2   text3
4    192.168.0.3    2   text4
```

I want to select but ignore duplicate by ip+port by last id , so the results will be

```
4, 192.168.0.3,2, text4
3, 192.168.0.1,2, text3
```

How can I do that with a T-SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ip, port order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```